# Refresh input class on input change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been trying for some time to refresh the classes of an input when it changes. I see that when the input changes, my function is called. However, I have to type a new letter in my input to refresh its classes. I would like that when I leave the input with the mouse and click somewhere else, the classes refresh (at the same time as when the bind @change is called)

My input:

```
<input
       type="email"
       class="form-control"
       v-model="student.email"
       placeholder="Email"
       @change="validateEmail(student.email)"
       :class="errors.has('live.student.email') ? 'is-invalid' : ''"
/>
```

My validateEmail function:

```
methods: {
    validateEmail(email) {
      if (/^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {
        this.errors.clear("live.student.email")
      } else {
        if (!this.errors.get("live.student.email"))
          this.errors.push({"live.student.email" : ["Email mal formaté"]})
      }
    }
}
```

My errors output on error triggered:

```
live.student.email: Array(1)
0: "Bad formatted"
length: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?:
Your input:

```
<input
       type="email"
       class="form-control"
       v-model="student.email"
       placeholder="Email"
       @mouseleave="mouseLeave(student.email)"
       @change="validateEmail(student.email)"
       :class="errors.has('live.student.email') ? 'is-invalid' : ''"
/>
```

The methode:

```js
methodes:{
mouseLeave(email) {
        //what to do
        validateEmail(email)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseleave` event handler.

something like

```
@mouseleave:"validateEmail(student.email)"
```

Comment: No changes with @mouseleave, I think the bug come from the errors object verification on class bind